# Why when I set a bigger number range in my palindrome finder, I get a wrong result?

Tags: python

I already got the correct number by tinkering with the range() functions but I wanted to know why when I run the following:

```
def isNumberPalindrome(number):

    condition = True
    digits = [x for x in str(number)]

    for index in range(0, int( len(digits) / 2)): 
        if digits[index] != digits[-(index + 1)]:
            condition = False  
            break 

    return condition
    

def largestPalindromeFinder():
    for leftFactor in range(999, 99, -1):
        for rightFactor in range(leftFactor, 99, -1): 
            candidate = leftFactor*rightFactor
            if isNumberPalindrome(candidate):
                return candidate


print(largestPalindromeFinder())
```

***I get a wrong result (580085). On the second loop, if you set the last number to be 600 you'll get the correct result. If you set it to 500, it starts getting that wrong result.***

Does this have something to do with how Python handles memory?

The idea is to find the largest palindrome from the multiplication of 2 3-digit numbers.

Comment: 580085 is a real result....

Comment: What is the expected behavior/result? 580085 seems like a palindrome to me

Comment: Not the largest one! The expected behaviour is to find the largest palindrome number. Which in fact it does IF you use a determined number on the inner loop...why that happens is what I am trying to find out.

Comment: You're not testing every number, only numbers that are multiples of `leftFactor` and `rightFactor`.

Comment: What is your search space supposed to be? The composites you are testing are not a comprehensive set of numbers between 0 and 999*999.

Comment: @4d4143 please be more specific, for us to be able to help. What is your logic, and what result you expected?

Comment: First you test `998,001`, then you test `997,002`, then `996001`, etc. You're skipping lots of possible palindromes.

Comment: @4d4143 If `580085` is not what you expect, then what is the largest one?

Comment: Added the logic behind the program!

Comment: I think, your problem statement is very very poor. You did not state clearly what you actually trying to find.

Comment: @biqarboy Just added the intention behind the program.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you think this code finds the _largest_ number meeting your criteria? You test e.g. `999*100` before `998*998`. Your coverage of the range is pretty sporadic

Comment: @Brian That's the bug.

Comment: @Brian I HIGHLY doubt Project Euler would accept a wrong answer. Guys, I got the correct result. Lets not focus on that. Please run it and check what Im saying regarding the inner loop which is what I am trying to figure out.

Comment: I think I see what you're trying to do. Did you intend for the range of `rightFactor` to be `range(999, leftFactor, -1)`? I.e, check `999*999`, `998*999`, `998*998`, `997*999`, `997*998`, `997*997`, so that the sequence is decreasing?

Comment: @Brian The program already does that. In fact if you put it that way it wont work (What you just wrote was my first attempt and it wouldnt give something back).
Here's the print output of the multiplications with my code:
999 x 999
999 x 998
999 x 997
999 x 996
999 x 995
999 x 994

Comment: That ordering might work. Change the inner loop to `range(999, leftFactor-1, -1)` @Brian Post it as an answer.

Comment: @4d4143 That's a different sequence, and its not decreasing. What number comes after `999*100`?

Comment: It will go to 998x998. Because its only 3-digits numbers and we already did 999x998. (It is decreasing. Ok cant edit the comment. So its decreasing but the comment formatting makes it appear as not decreasing).

Comment: @Brian Sorry Brian but I dont follow. Why would the code give the same answer if 900 or 800 or 700 are set as the stop number but with 500 it gives a different answer?

Comment: @4d4143 can you specify what is the answer you expect for different combinations of numbers?

Comment: @4d4143 Because some product of the form `999*n` where `n` is between `700` and `500` is a palindrome. That number is smaller than all of the numbers of the form `998*n` where `n` is between `999` and `701`. Your code checks smaller numbers before larger numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your approach. You are running two nested loops and returning the first palindrome you get. But, this may not be the largest one. For example, in your case, you construct a palindrome by multiplying `995` and `583` (and thus getting `580085`). On the other hand, you can create another palindromic number (e.g., `906609`) by multiplying `993` and `913`. Now, clearly the largest palindromic number (e.g., `906609`) will be generated later due to the way you run the nested loops. I assume you return just after finding the first palindrome as part of optimization. So, I think you can solve the problem by:

1. Either, let the loop finish (with some minor optimization, please check the code) and track the largest palindromic number.
2. Or, device a different algorithm that can solve your problem more efficiently.

Here I am sharing the code by applying `1`:

```
def isNumberPalindrome(number):

    condition = True
    digits = [x for x in str(number)]

    for index in range(0, int( len(digits) / 2)): 
        if digits[index] != digits[-(index + 1)]:
            condition = False  
            break 

    return condition
    

def largestPalindromeFinder():
    ret = 1;
    for leftFactor in range(999, 99, -1):
        for rightFactor in range(leftFactor, 99, -1): 
            candidate = leftFactor*rightFactor

            # loop optimization: we can safely break here, as the candidate is less than the already discovered palindromic number
            if (candidate < ret):
                break
            if isNumberPalindrome(candidate):
                if candidate > ret:
                    print("palindrom-number: {}, left-factor: {}, right-factor: {}".format(candidate, leftFactor, rightFactor))
                    ret = candidate
    
    return ret


print(largestPalindromeFinder())
```

Output:

```
palindrom-number: 580085, left-factor: 995, right-factor: 583
palindrom-number: 906609, left-factor: 993, right-factor: 913
906609
```

I have added some log print to help you understand the process.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your ordering isn't correct.

First you're testing all the multiples of `999` by other 3-digit numbers, so that goes from `998001` down to `99900` in steps of `999`. Then you try multiples of `998`, so you go back up to `996004` and work your way down to `99800` in steps of `998`. And so on.

The correct result is `993 x 913`. Your agorithm is returning `995 x 583` because it tests all multiples of `995` before it tests any multiples of `993` (except for `995 x 993`, but it's not a palindrome). If you change the lower limit in your range to something above `583`, you never get to `995 x 583`, so you end up returning the correct result. But the only way to know what to use as the lower limit is by already knowing what the correct result should be, but the whole point of the function is to find that result without knowing it.

So the first palindrome it finds won't necessarily be the largest, because you keep going up and down.

I'm not sure of an efficient algorithm, but you could simply make a list of all multiples of 3-digit numbers, sort the list in decrementing order, then search it to find the first one that's a palindrome.

```
def largestPalindromFinder():
    candidates = []
    for leftFactor in range(100, 999):
        for rightFactor in range(100, leftFactor+1):
            candidates.append(leftFactor * rightFactor)
    candidates.sort(rev = True)
    for number in candidates:
        if isNumberPalindrom(number):
            return number
```

Comment: The issue at hand: Figuring out why when I put a X number as the stop in the inner loop's range, it gives back the correct answer. Swap it for a lower Y number (Thus increasing the amount of multiplications) and it will back a wrong answer.

Comment: It's just a coincidence. When you make the inner loop stop sooner, you skip some lower palindromes that are multiples of higher `leftFactor`. Eventually you filter out all the ones that are lower than the result you want.

Comment: Suppose the palindromes are `998 * 200` and `995 * 600`. If you change the inner loop to stop at `500` you'll never see `998 * 200`.

Comment: And thats perfect! I want to find the largest one! Try my code. Start changing the stop number. 900, 800, 700, 600 will give you all the same answer. Change it to 500 and suddenly we get another number. Does not make sense at all. Got what I am saying?

Comment: I just explained it. It's just by accident, there's no way to know where to stop. If you fix the algorithm you don't need to guess where to stop.

Comment: Tinkering with the range is not a proper approach, since it's based on already knowing what the correct result is supposed to be, and changing the algorithm until it returns what you want. But if you're going to do that, you could just get rid of the whole algorithm and just return the result directly.

Comment: Ok. I'll try to word it differently. I got a result trying from 999x999 until 100x100. Project Euler (the webpage) said it was wrong. I checked the multiplications being made. They are correct. No number is being skipped. Changed it to stop at 600x600. Got another answer and now this is the correct one. It SHOULD be the same answer if I change it back again to 100x100 because its the largest one. That is NOT happening. Get what Im saying?

Comment: I get what you're saying. I explained the problem in the first paragraph of my answer.

Comment: The correct answer is `993*913`. You're returning `995*583`. The problem is that you're testing all multiples of `995` before you test multiples of `993`. If you stop at `600*600`, you never test `995*583`. It's just by pure luck that stopping at 600 gives the correct answer.

Comment: Sorry for being EXTREMELY dense.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to find the largest number between 99 and 999*999 that is a palindrome.
In that case, the function you have does not process every number. As per @Barmar comment First you test 998,001, then you test 997,002, then 996001, etc. You're skipping lots of possible palindromes.

To test all numbers, you can change your function to something like this:

EDIT 1: Edited the answer to reflect the required logic.
You can specify the required number to the function as arguments, then validate whether they have 3 digits (if necessary)

```py
def largestPalindromeFinder(leftFactor, rightFactor):
    if (99 < leftFactor < 1000) and (99 < rightFactor < 1000):
        for candidate in range(leftFactor*rightFactor, 99, -1):
                if isNumberPalindrome(candidate):
                    return candidate
    else:
        return 'invalid number provided'

print(largestPalindromeFinder(999, 123)) # 122221
```

Comment: Read the last line of the edited question.

Comment: 997799 isn't the product of two 3-digit numbers.

Comment: Where does 123 come from?

Comment: As far as I understand the palindrom has to be up to the product of two 3 digit numbers, not to be a product itself. So this function accepts arbitrary 3 digit numbers

Comment: That's not how I understand it. It's the largest palindrome that's a product of any two 3-digit numbers.

Comment: @Barmar It's just an example I guess

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to find the largest palindrome that is the product of two 3-digit numbers by iterating over all such products in a decreasing sequence. That way, the first match you find will be largest that exists, right?

The problem is that your search sequence *isn't* decreasing. Currently, the order in which you iterate over the products of 3 digit numbers is

```
999*999, 999*998, 999*997, ..., 999*101, 999*100, 998*998, 998*997,...
```

As you can see, we make a rather large jump *up* magnitude just after `999*100`, rising from 99,900 to 996,004. This happens several times in your sequence.

You can fix this by tweaking the range of your inner loop. The decreasing sequence we want is

```
999*999, 998*999, 998*998, 997*999, 997*998, 997*997, ...
```

To generate this sequence, change your inner loop from

```
for rightFactor in range(leftFactor, 99, -1):
```

to

```
for rightFactor in range(999, leftFactor - 1, -1):
```